# How many combinations are possible of $\{1,2,3\}$ with returning

Tags: combinatorics

> How many combinations are possible of $\{1,2,3\}$ with returning?

You are picking numbers. I know it is very easy, but I got little confused.

Comment: To be sure that I understand: you’re choosing numbers from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ with replacement. How many are you choosing? Do you care about the order in which they are chosen, or just about how many of each number is chosen?

Comment: Hmm, lets say that at least one 3 has to always be picked. You are choosing 3 numbers. You pick number, write it down, than return to array.

Answer (score 1):

All possible combinations are
$$111$$
$$112,121,211$$
$$113,131,311$$
$$122,212,221$$
$$123,132,213,231,312,321$$
$$133,313,331$$
$$222$$
$$223,232,322$$
$$233,323,332$$
$$333$$

Comment: can you get that number without writing them all down ?

Comment: yes, that is $3^3=27$ in general picking k numbers from n formula is $n^k$

Comment: what if 3 has to always be picked ?

Comment: 3 from n then exists $n^3$ combinations

Comment: what is n, and what m ?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate choosing $n$ numbers with replacement you use, $$\binom{n+m-1}{m}$$

where $n$ in the total numbers in the set, and m is how many numbers you want to choose.

For $\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$, $n$ is $3$ & $m$ is $1$. 
$$\binom{3}{1} \implies C_1^3$$

First choice: You have $3$ to chose $1$ - $C_1^3$

This remains the same for the second and third choices since you replaced the number you drew - $C_1^3$

So the number of combinations possible are $C_1^3 \cdot C_1^3  \cdot C_1^3 = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 27$

---

If $3$ has to always be picked then:

All Possible Combinations - Combination where $3$ are not picked = Combinations where $3$ is always picked

$$= 27 - 8 = 19$$

**Combinations where $3$ is not picked:**

For $\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$ to get no $3$'s

First, second and third choices will be $C_1^2$ since you can only choose $1$ or $2$

$$C_1^2 \cdot C_1^2 \cdot C_1^2 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8$$

Comment: what if 3 has to always be picked ?

Comment: If the number $3$ has to always be picked?

Comment: Yes, in every picking, you are sure that 3 will be picked.

Comment: @user2982390 Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: how you got 19 ?

Comment: I actually found the combinations that has no $3$ picked in them and subtracted that from the total number of combinations. See under the bolded title where I calculated the combinations where $3$ is not picked. That result was $8$, then I subtratced $8$ from $27$ (the total number of combinations possible) to get $19$.

Comment: I see, but how you found that combinations ?

Comment: I didn't find that there were $19$ combinations like how I did with $27$ or $8$. I used the equation All combinations $-$ Combinations without $3$ - worked both of those Combinations out and then arrived that there if $3$ has to be picked there are $19$ combinations.

Comment: Can you write that equation, that was I'm asking for:)

Comment: It's not a known equation/formula if that's what you think..In fact, I made up that equation to suit this question, where logically subtracting a subset of a group from the total will yield the remainder. For instance a bag has 5 balls, 3 are red, the rest are blue. To find blue you would subtract red $(2)$ from the total $(5)$ to get $5 - 2 = 3$ blue. Understand?

Comment: That was that obvious, sorry for bothering you, I'm just tired. Thank you for being nice and patient. :)

Comment: No problem, remember to up-vote if the answers were useful & accept an answer as the best answer.

Comment: I would, but the system doesn't let me do that because of low reputation :(